# Testing of In-App-Purchasing in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, jailbreak, unlock

I am using In-App-Purchasing first time in ios,for this i have follow the steps which is given on following links.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

and

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_in_app_purchase.htm

I have add two consumables product in my application on itunes connect.
create and download new provisioning profile and configure it with my project.
create test user for testing in-app-purchase

my issue is

"response.products.count" is empty on device AND on simulator it returns 2(which is correct product).

I don't know why it is not working on device.

(1). Can we test In-App-Purchasing with sandbox mode on "unlock devices" ?

(2). Can we test In-App-Purchasing with sandbox mode on "Jailbreak Devices" ?

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: if a device is Jailbreak or unlocked it doesn't matter in in-app purchase
In-app-purchase works on all ios devices

Comment: thanks for comment,is in-app-purchase testing(sandbox mode) is all so work on Jailbreak and unlocked devices ?

Comment: yes it will work on both types of devices

Comment: Thanks for useful comment,can you please help me to resolve this issue what is wrong in my case.getting correct product count on simulator but on devices this is empty.

Comment: please follow this link there is step by step proce dure described. may be possible you miss something.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug from apple server side. because from last couple of days many test accounts are not working.

**fix this issue, I simply registered a new user in iTunesConnect, but I set their store to 'USA'.**

Comment: "response.products.count" is empty on device AND on simulator it returns 2(which is correct product count). if this issue from apple server side then how it is working on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

for testing in app purchase check that in device you are not logged in to app store from apple id
if you are logged in App Store then sign out all of account and then test in app purchase within application..

Comment: i am using correct provisioning profile which is created for this app and i have also create new bundle id which is not wildcard bundle identifier, when i test my app on devices then first i remove old app from devices and install new fresh app.i don't know what i am doing wrong,please help

Comment: I already have two certificate "iOS Development" & "iOS Distribution". Is it compulsory to create and download new certificate when creating new identifier and provisioning profiles for In-App-Purchase ?

Comment: you can use this link for Adding In-App Purchase to your iOS and Mac Applications [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some times there will be problem while fetching products from server if your application works in simulator then it will working fine with your Device ....just checkout your certificate that you used for testing in device and also checkout sandbox account ..it working try thanks...

Comment: i have already check both of them multiple times both of this is correct.